# Yup validation throw error on specific word

Tags: node.js, reactjs, yup

Using yup how can i make it so if value of boughtby === "none" then it should throw a error. Since now it only works if value is "" but I wanna make is so if the value is "none" than it also throws a error.

```
const NewUserSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    createDate: Yup.string().nullable().required('Create date is required'),
    boughtby: Yup.string().required("Cannot be none")
  });
  const defaultValues = useMemo(
    () => ({
      createDate: details?.dealDetails[0]?.created_date || null,
      // I would like this to have "none" as default value, it accepts
      // the value if it is "none" but it throws error if it is "".
      // How do I implement so it throws error on both?
      boughtby: details?.dealDetails[0]?.bought_by || "",
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    [details]
  );
  const methods = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(NewUserSchema),
    defaultValues,
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can do this is via regex, by accepting any value that is not `"none"`:

```js
const NewUserSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  createDate: Yup.string().nullable().required('Create date is required'),
  boughtby: Yup.string().matches(/^(?!none).*$/, "Cannot be none").required("Cannot be none")
});
```

Comment: I was thinking of doing it like that, but it then tells me as the error
`boughtby must match the following: "/^(?!none).*$/"` so I was looking for something else since it says "Must match"

Comment: @OleDybedokken tells you that error for what input? And can you elaborate on `looking for something else since it says "Must match"`?

Comment: `boughtby: Yup.string().matches(/^(?!none).*$/, 'Cannot be none').required("Cannot be none")` This fixed my issue. Thanks